# How to change Unity's default login screen to allow users to type in their logins and passwords?

Tags: unity, 12.04, login, lightdm

Installed Pangolin 12.04 X64 I would like to change the login screen. The default screen let's you choose the user by scrolling which can be a nightmare if you have a lot of users. I just want the user to type login and password.

Answer (score 7):

## Using LightDM

Edit the the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` using this command

```
gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And add these two lines to the `[SeatDefaults]` section

```
greeter-hide-users=true
allow-guest=false
```

---

*Taken From*: http://www.puppychau.com/archives/130