# How to enable the "Other User" login in ubuntu 12.04 if the userid I want to use isn't listed on the login screen?

Tags: login, lightdm

How can I enable the "Other User" option for the login manager in ubuntu 12.04? This was available in older versions of Ubuntu for use in logging in with a user-id other than those listed on the login manager.

Comment: Other? As in guest?

Comment: no, actually I mean "Other" for another user account. Just like in 11.10 ,

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/135053/45659 Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yeah, but that one is not really what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `greeter-show-manual-login=true` to file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. For example:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Comment: Is is possible to only show manual login? (to hide possible users)

Comment: Add `greeter-hide-users=true` line.