# How can I require users to also enter their usernames upon login?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

Good day,

Does anyone know how to modify the login screen so that users are required to type their username along with their password?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with all default settings

Comment: Have you tried adding User accounts in System setting?

Comment: I will be using a mix of ldap users and local users so just want the ability for users to just type their name rather than select from a list

Comment: I have seen this question answered before here, i will have a look for the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Unity's default login screen to allow users to type in their logins and passwords?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135053/how-to-change-unitys-default-login-screen-to-allow-users-to-type-in-their-login)

Comment: See also: [Ask for username and password on 18's login screen](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037289/327339)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need three settings in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to get exactly what you want:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login = true
greeter-hide-users = true
allow-guest = false
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I've found one option that seems to work partially

add `greeter-show-manual-login = true` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and then reboot.

It still shows local accounts which is not ideal but does allow me to log in with ldap user accounts now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kubuntu, the above does NOT work due to a bug in the kde greeter

Create this file: **/etc/lightdm/lightdm-kde-greeter.conf** and include the following contents.

```
[greeter]
theme-name=classic
```

Answer (score 0):

*Tested in Ubuntu 22.04 just now.*

Source where I learned this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1037289/327339

```bash
sudo nano /usr/share/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults
```

Find the line where it says this:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
```

...and underneath it, uncomment this:

```
disable-user-list=true
```

(Required): then, run this:

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Now reboot to test it:

```bash
reboot
```