# Ask for username and password on 18's login screen

Tags: login, login-screen, gdm

I'm using the latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS bionic.

When I login it shows my username and I just need to type a password.

*I don't want usernames to be shown.* I want to be forced to type a username and password.

How do I do that? All I found is info for old versions or lightdm (18 uses gdm).

Comment: I tried using "dconf editor" to edit the `org/gnome/login-screen/disable-user-list` but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you try any of the other solutions recommended by the answers to the linked question, namely the first part of [ravery's answer](/a/979745/175814) which is nearly the the same as one of Rinzwind's suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Settings for gdm3 are done in `/usr/share/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults`.

Uncomment these 2 lines:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
disable-user-list=true
```

(Only un-commenting the 2nd line will crash your login: [bugreport confirming it works for 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1724944)) and restart the login manager with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

and reboot (or restart with `sudo systemctl stop gdm` and log out).

Make a backup 1st so in case something get messed up and you can not log in you can use tty3 to redo your changes. edit: this wont work; gdm also takes care of the tty sessions so tty3 is dead too... you will need to user a live session or grub rescue prompt.

---

Another way that works for 17.10 and 18.04 (from comment #7 by fprietog in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1724944/comments/7)):

> Using root:
>
> - Create a file named `/etc/dconf/profile/gdm` with this contents:
>
>   ```
>    user-db:user   
>    system-db:gdm
>   ```
> - Create a file named `/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/50-disable-user-list` with this content:
>
>   ```
>   [org/gnome/login-screen]   
>   disable-user-list=true
>   ```
> - Execute the command `sudo dconf update`

Comment: Tried that but it gives me errors when I run `dpkg-reconfigure` (something about keyfiles - not sure why because I haven't changed anything major in my new ubuntu install). I rebooted ad then it didn't even show the login prompt. So I went into tty3 and undid the change, and now I can login again as before. But I'm stuck where I was before. :(

Comment: @lonix It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1724944

Comment: @pomsky added :-)

Comment: I summarized your answer here too: [How can I require users to also enter their usernames upon login?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1445984/327339).