# Select account based on password instead of username

Tags: 12.04, login, password, login-screen

Sometimes I might be forced to open my PC in front of strangers for some reason.

In front of other people, I would like to make it appear that I'm logging in normally into my computer, but secretly I will be entering a special "panic password" - not my usual password - such that the system will redirect the login to some other preprepared user account designed for this situation.

In other words, I need some place to put some code that will check the password input and then make the decision whether to log into the main user account I use every day or to log into the dummy one, while on the login screen only one account appears.

Is that possible? Where is the code that get executed when I press enter to login? Or is it a Unity thing?

I know it might seem silly but believe me it's *life saving*.

Comment: I don't have an answer for what you want. However, I have a suggestion. You can disable the predefined user names, and make the system prompt for you to type the user name first and password second. If you do this, you can create two similar user IDs with different passwords, for regular use and panic use. The userIDs need to be different. The two names can be identical to confuse others. See [How to change unity's default login screen to allow users to type in their login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135053/how-to-change-unitys-default-login-screen-to-allow-users-to-type-in-their-login)

Comment: You rally can not do what you envision easiy. My best advice in this situation is to fully encrypt your installs. Use one install for every day use and a second install for your situation. With LUKS you can have more then one password, so enter a different password for each install. The difference would be in the gurb configuration for each install, one pointing to your usuall install and the second to your backup.

Comment: Be warned, if people have physical access you really can not hide accounts or information, worse case scenario they would boot a live usb or ask you to log in as root, and in either event have full access to your information. Encryption is the best you can do.

Comment: Why not encrypt your disc and create a 2nd account and use that?

Comment: It's not the lost of the pc that I'm affraid of, that Encryption will solve. But mr.user68186's suggestion I think is the best to my situation thank you all very much.

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 see http://askubuntu.com/questions/451950/how-to-configure-lightdm-to-allow-manual-logins-in-ubuntu-14-04