# How to configure lightdm to allow manual logins in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login, lightdm

I used to modify `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, adding the line `greeter-show-manual-login=true`, in order to allow login for hidden users and root.

Now I've just installed the new Ubuntu 14.04 and the file `lightdm.conf` is no longer located in `/etc/lightdm`. It's in `/etc/init` and has been totally modified.

How can I force lightdm login screen to show a field to input a login name?

Answer (score 30):

Ok I finally found the solution, very simple. The file to edit is now located in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`, and is called: `50-ubuntu.conf`.

I just added the line:

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

and on next reboot I was able to input any user name on the login screen.

[image]

Comment: Rather than editing a default system file, why not add your own to the lightdm.conf.d folder?

Comment: If you do make a completely new file as suggested by @bshacklett, you need to start it with `[SeatDefaults]`.

Comment: For Plasma, the file is `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-kde-plasma-kf5.conf`

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 installation. But I resolved the problem by following [this](http://www.tejasbarot.com/2014/04/25/hide-users-login-as-other-user-from-login-screen-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr/#axzz30emfVH8c) site.

The solution is to create a file `lightdm.conf` inside `/etc/lightdm/` and put the following contents in it:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

After a system reboot, I was able to login with other users.

Comment: On the Ubuntu 14.04 64bit the configuration file changed to /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf But on 32bit is same as before

Answer (score 0):

Also you should do following step:

update `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and change the line:

```
session sufficient pam_lsass.so
```

to:

```
session [success=ok default=ignore] pam_lsass.s
```

After a reboot, my path was ok, and everything seems to be working as normal again.

See the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1228079)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `greeter-show-manual-login=true` option, one could use `greeter-hide-users=true`. Personally that's that I have in my `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` : the manual login option is commented out, with only hide users option left.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this option only allows login as a guest user.

Comment: @gone no, login is allowed for all users, not just guest.  You just have to type username, instead of  choosing from a list in the greeter

Comment: Not on my install.  There is no where to type a username.  There's just a label with `Guest Session` and the button `Log In   >`, and if you click or press enter, the guest user logs in.  Using the up/down arrows does not help either. Switching users after logging in as guest also doesn't work.

Comment: @gone And what version of Ubuntu you're using ?

Comment: U14.04.3 LTS in a VirtualBox VM on a Macbook Pro with MacOS.