# How do I enable/disable guest account in Trusty 14.04.1

Tags: users, unity-greeter, accounts

Only my user is shown on greeter, guest is not, my wife is not. This is a system I reinstalled from 12.04-i386 to 14.04-amd64, reformating all but /home.
Even a user created from Trusty won't show on greeter.
The only way these 3 can log in is from my own system menu switch user feature.
I dug a bit and discovered I have the ~new ?~ AccountService thing installed, so that all tricks I found around about lightdm are now out of scope.
**(please change the text about unity-greeter tag saying lightdm is underlying)**

Comment: `accountsservice` was also used in 12.04. I don't think the tricks are dead yet

Comment: Well the problem is that I do not have any /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file from which I could remove `allow-guest=false` (or add `allow-guest=true`, in the case missing `allow-guest=` line wouldn't be enough to restore the default behaviour). More, I read this in the lonesome `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`:  `#
    # User accounts configuration
    #
    # NOTE: If you have AccountsService installed on your system, then LightDM will
    # use this instead and these settings will be ignored 
    #
    # minimum-uid = Minimum UID required to be shown in greeter
    # hidden-users = Users that are ...`

Comment: That's because `lightdm` is using a more flexible way of handling configuration. Have a look at this directory: `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/451950/how-to-configure-lightdm-to-allow-manual-logins-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Own answer to own question:
This ~bug~ was supplied by myself: the workaround was to download my glasses from the shelf to see that white font of users name on the ~white~ greeter from `usr/share/backgrounds/Foggy_Forest_by_Jake_Stewart.jpg` I choose myself running `dconf-editor` as lightdm user, is simply of poor contrast....
Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Best. Bug. Ever.

Comment: No bounty for this? At least for my own answer ;-)