# How to log in to an account which is hidden from the lightdm login screen?

Tags: login, lightdm, users

I followed the accepted answer of [How do I hide a particular user from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92349/367990) (the one about modifying `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/USERNAME`) to hide the user `guest-config` from my lightdm login screen.

This works fine and the account vanished from the user list after a reboot.

However, now I need a way to log into that account anyway. On Windows (at least back on good old Windows XP), I could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> twice on the login screen to get an old-school login mask prompting me to type the username and password manually. This does not work on Ubuntu.

How can I get a similar graphical login mask where I must enter the username manually? I don't want to lose the normal user list for all other visible accounts though. Just add this to log into invisible accounts.

System is Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Desktop.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451950/how-to-configure-lightdm-to-allow-manual-logins-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @muru Wonderful! Nothing beats your dupe finding skills! :D Thank you.