# list of users under "lock/switch account"

Tags: unity

16.04.2 When one clicks on the gearswitch thing at top right (to log out or shutdown), there is a list of users, can this list be suppressed somehow?

Edited to add: Need to set this for all users, not just the logged in user.

Comment: This is the list of all users that are visible on the login screen. Hide users there to also make them disappear in that list.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, added to users.conf, display of user added to hidden-users line persists.

Comment: No, you must append the two lines from that answer to `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/USERNAME`, not to `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`! This way it won't work, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is controlled via `gsettings`. To disable showing other usernames in the panel, run the following in terminal

```
$ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu  false
```

Compare:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This only sets it to false for the logged-in user.  Is there a way to set it for all users?

Comment: @alabamatoy I believe there is, but will need to test a couple things first. In the mean time, please update your question. This requirement was not in your original post. The amount of clarity you put into your question will reflect the answers you receive

Answer (score 0):

**This answer helps you if you want to hide one (or several) specific accounts from the list.

If you want to disable the list completely and show no users (except guest account), follow [*@Serg*'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/890269/367990).**

The presence of an account in the system menu's user list is connected to whether it shows up in the lightdm greeter/login screen.

To hide a user in both places, you may follow e.g. [this answer by Marc Culler](https://askubuntu.com/a/575390/367990) (tested by me on Ubuntu 16.04), which can be summarized as

> create a file named
>
> ```
> /var/lib/AccountsService/users/XXX
> ```
>
> containing two lines:
>
> ```
> [User]
> SystemAccount=true
> ```
>
> If the file already exists, make sure you append the `SystemAccount=true` line to the `[User]` section.

Now in order to still be able to log into an account hidden this way through the GUI, you have to enable manual logins in lightdm, which allows you to type in any username. See [How to configure lightdm to allow manual logins in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/451950/367990) for more information about this.