# Allow arbitrary username on login screen

Tags: login-screen

Is there a way to allow typing in an arbitrary username from the login screen?

My use case is that I want to be able to hide users from the login screen, but still be able to login as those users. I was able to figure out hiding the users using the config files under /var/lib/AccountsService/users but now there's no way to log in as them.

Under lightdm this option seems to have been available. Can it still be done?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? AFAIK the method described in [How to configure lightdm to allow manual logins in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/451980/178692) works at least up to 16.04 i.e. creating a `[SeatDefaults]` section containing `greeter-show-manual-login=true` in the appropriate conf file (I'd suggest something like `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-manual-login.conf`)