# Can't enable root login on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, root, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Vmware.

I followed these instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdyy7icpgbQ

But when restarting, I'm getting this:
[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

... as shown in the video.

How to enable the login as root?

---

### Additional

Here a video to show the process:
 [image]

---

### After Conclusion step

[image]
[image]

### Solution

After a lot of support of [Marmayogi](https://askubuntu.com/users/617387/marmayogi), the best solution found was to keep `lightdm`, detailed [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50201918#50201918):

Comment: Please do **NOT** login as root. Debian/Ubuntu has it disabled by default for a good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## How to Configure gdm3 to allow root login?

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with GDM (Gnome Display Manager) as a default Display Manager. For Security reason user can’t login with `root` user.
For development and advanced operation, some user may prefer to login as `root`.

Follow the steps to enable root login on Ubuntu 18.04 GDM display manager.

## Step-1: Modify `GDM conf` file.

Before doing any changes take a back up:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/gdm3/custom.conf /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.original
```

Now open up  `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` with `vi` editor as follows:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Copy and paste the following two lines below `[Security]` directive.

```
[Security]
AllowRoot = true
AllowRemoteRoot = true
```

Save and exit from the editor.

## Step-2: Modify `PAM conf` file.

Now modify PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) configuration file.

Before doing any changes take a back up:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/pam.d/gdm-password /etc/pam.d/gdm-password.original
```

Now open up  `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password` with `vi` editor as follows:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/pam.d/gdm-password
```

In the file, search for the following line:

```
auth    required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
```

To comment the line just add `#` in front of the line as shown below:

```
#auth   required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
```

Save and exit from the editor.

> **Note:** This step was incomplete in the [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdyy7icpgbQ) provided in the post by the Questioner.

## Step-3: Reboot

After reboot, you will reach login screen where there will be a display of  **`not listed?`** option just under username. If you click it, you will get another screen where you can enter `root` as username and then press `next` button. Now, the next screen appears which collects `password`. You enter root password.  After successful  authentication you will be logged in as `root`.

## Conclusion:

Questioner `@Rogério Dec` attempts to look for username `root`  from `lightdm` login screen.

> This procedure is for gnome GDM according to the **youtube** video.

If you have not installed gnome desktop, then install the same using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

If you have already installed both `lightdm` as well as `gdm3`, then you need to switch to `gdm` through following command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

After switched to `gdm3`, follow **step-3** to login as `root`.

Comment: Thank you @Rogério Dec for pointing out path error in `cp` command. And also `vi` & `gedit` mixup.

Comment: Thanks, I did your steps but it seems to have made no difference. To confirm the steps I performed, I posted a video on the original question so you can track what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: You are in `lightdm` whereas this root-login procedure is for `gdm`. So you need to switch to `gdm` for root-login to work. If you issue this command `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`, the ouput on your terminal will be `/usr/sbin/lightdm`. Suppose the output is `/usr/sbin/gdm3`, then the root-login process will work. Please follow up the `Conclusion` part of the answer in order to switch to `gdm`. If you have more questions, please let me know!

Comment: Suppose you don't want to switch to `gdm` and you want continue with `lightdm` display manager and still want to do root-login. Then you should follow  https://askubuntu.com/questions/451950/how-to-configure-lightdm-to-allow-manual-logins-in-ubuntu-14-04. **A word of caution:** this link offers solution for Ubuntu 14.04 lightdm but your version of ubuntu is 18.04. So, please double-check before using the solution.

Comment: I did the "Conclusion" step, but now I can't log in anymore, even with my old user. I inserted 2 images at the end of the original post to illustrate.

Comment: I restored a backup from my virtual machine and redid the steps. 
I noticed that after `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
` I get `gdm.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93319/discussion-between-marmayogi-and-rogerio-dec).

Comment: What's the solution you came to in chat? I have the same problem, and I can't login as root or my user through the GUI. However, I can login as either root or my user through open-SSH server or OpenVPN. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason for this behaviour is that you haven't set a root password. I know the Ubuntu install should force this, but if for any reason it glitches, you can do the following in a terminal :

```
sudo passwd root
```

As described in this post :
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-and-disable-root-user-account-in-ubuntu/